# How to add a dropdownbox in particular cell in JTable, something like microsoft excel?

Tags: java, swing

How to add a dropdownbox in particular cell in JTable, something like microsoft excel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[*Writing a Custom Cell Renderer*](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html#renderer) discusses this topic and links to similar examples. [*Concepts: Editors and Renderers*](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender) elaborates on the notion of custom renderers and editors.

Answer (score 1):

You should implement the table cell editor based on JComboBox. Here is the starting point:
http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#combobox